# How to make a multi line text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Sometimes, the text widget does a line break, and sometimes don't. I tried to add overflow and `maxline` but it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
Text(
  ArticleData().articleBank[index].articleTitle,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 20.0,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```

This is what, I will try to build:

[image: App]

Comment: Please try to put your Text widget inside the `Flexible` or `Expanded` Widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FittedBox` class.

Scales and positions its child within itself according to fit. The fit and alignment arguments must not be null.

```
FittedBox(
  Key key,
  fit: BoxFit.none,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text(
    ArticleData().articleBank[index].articleTitle,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I try it, The Text() change it fontSize and show in single linge